# Getting dynamic token from ChatBot URL in iFrame

Tags: botframework, bots, chatbot

I am working on ChatBot development using MS BOTFramework. URL of my ChatBot is [This](https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/testbot) . I am using this in iFrame like below code -

```
{iframe src="https://webchat.botframework.com/embed/testbot?sess=dynamic_value" width = "455" height = "600"}

{/iframe}.
```

I want to get dynamic value of **sess** inside Bot code for user authentication.
I have tried this [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38098335/is-there-any-way-to-access-the-generated-token-value-for-web-chat-from-inside-th#)

```
ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new System.Uri(message.ServiceUrl));
```

any workaround for this?

Comment: Could you please try to describe what you are asking better.  It's unclear exactly what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done with the iframed version.  You would need to host the webchat on a page of your own in your site, then use `const params = BotChat.queryParams(location.search);` to access the query string parameters on the page.  If you want to have the query parameters in the bot, you would need to send a backchannel event that contains the parameters and handle that event within the bot.

Here is an example of how to send a backchannel event: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/blob/master/samples/backchannel/index.html

Comment: Thanks Eric for your reply. is this possible to use backchannel feature with .Net based BOT

Comment: Yes... backchannel is a feature of webchat and directline.js.  It provides a mechanism for sending events between bot and client instead of messages.  These events can be handled by a node bot OR a .net based bot.